# powershell returns date with "∩╗┐" in front when running in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have powershell `get-date` command in my batch script, when executing the batch files I get this weird `∩╗┐` symbols in front of my result.

My batch is encoding in ANSI, and I have changed the code page to **chcp 437** before running it.

This is my code:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%a in (`"powershell (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MMdd');"`) do if not defined MMdd set MMdd=%%a
```

It return me something like this `∩╗┐0604` and when I receive the error from email it shows me `n++0604`. This error data not always appears. Any ideas how to get rid of this `∩╗┐`?

Comment: Those characters occupy code points `EF BB BF` in code page 437, which is the Unicode byte-order mark in UTF-8. PowerShell should not normally use UTF-8 -- if you do not change the `$OutputEncoding`, the default is ASCII, which will not produce the BOM. Try changing `$OutputEncoding` to `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, or else try using code page 65001 (in recent versions of Windows).

Comment: If you've stated a string format `MMdd` then you should only receive the string `0604` with nothing else. The 'error' data appears to be UTF-8, so start by using the `-NoProfile` parameter and protect your output using doublequotes too: `For /F %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MMdd')"') Do Set "MMdd=%%A"`.

Comment: @Compo follow your way but the UTF-8 data still appear, by the way that error data only appear sometimes and sometimes it is just ok.

Comment: We need more information, the script snippet you're showing in your question does not output anything at all, it just sets a variable.Batch file, powershell email suggests it's being written somewhere, so please post a more relevant code section by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50814503/edit) accordingly.